# comment form code redirect to wp_comments_post.php with blank page

Tags: comments, forms

comment form in single post worked well. then after adding some customization, after posting a comment, it redirects to this link wp_comments_post.php with blank page.

Here is my code in comments.php so what is wrong here to make it work again?

```
<?php
$form_args = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'author' => ' <form class="getin_form" id="post-a-comment"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">  <div class="form-group bottom35"> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name:" required  style=" border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5; border-radius: 0; padding: 12px 0;box-shadow: none;height: 44px;color: #a5a5a5;font-size: 14px;position: relative; "> </div> </div>',
        'email' => ' <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">  <div class="form-group bottom35"> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email:" required id="email" name="email" style=" border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5; border-radius: 0; padding: 12px 0;box-shadow: none;height: 44px;color: #a5a5a5;font-size: 14px;position: relative; "> </div> </div> ',

    ),
        
        // change the title of the reply section
        'title_reply'=>'Add Comment',
        // remove "Text or HTML to be displayed after the set of comment fields"
        'comment_notes_after' => '',
        // redefine your own textarea (the comment body)
        'comment_field' => '  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <div class="form-group bottom35"> <p class="comment-form-comment"><div class="form-group"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label><br />  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message"  style=" border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5; border-radius: 0; box-shadow: none; " aria-required="true"></textarea></p> </div></div> ',
        'submit_field' =>' <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;"> <button type="submit" class="button btnprimary form-control"> submit request </button> </div> </div> </form> </div> </div> </div> </div>',

);

comment_form($form_args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other issues in your code or the `$form_args` array items, but the main ones are:

1. The blank page is due to missing hidden comment fields for replying to comments — see [`get_comment_id_fields()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_id_fields/), where the fields are in the `submit_field` arg by default.

   So to quickly fix that, add `%2$s` in that arg like so:

   ```php
   'submit_field' => '... <button type="submit" class="button btnprimary form-control"> submit request </button> %2$s ...',
   ```

   But you should actually use the `submit_button` arg to customize the submit button HTML, then with the `submit_field` arg, use something like:

   ```php
   'submit_field' => '<div>%1$s %2$s</div>',
   ```
2. The comment `textarea` field needs to have its `name` set to `comment`.

   ```php
   'comment_field' => '... <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" ... name="comment"> ...',
   ```
3. Please, make sure your HTML is valid — you've got an unwanted `</form>` tag in the `submit_field` arg. :(

I hope that helps and please review the [`comment_form()` reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/) for details on the other args, and other relevant details/resources.

Comment: @ Sally CJ thanks so much for your helpful reply